# Decrement integer in postgres only if larger than a minimum

Tags: postgresql

I have a statement like this, that I use to decrement a counter:

```
UPDATE stats SET counter = counter - 1 WHERE id = 24235;
```

The problem is, that I never want the counter to go below `1`. How do I execute an update statement, that will only decrement down till `1`?

PG version 9.3

Comment: What version of Postgres, please?

Comment: I was bamboozled same as you to go down the path of conditional programming looking for a special Postgres IF statement. A WHERE condition will do it.

Answer (score 10):

```
UPDATE stats
SET counter = counter - 1
WHERE id = 24235
  AND counter > 1;
```

If the decrementing amount varies, you have to make sure to pass in the same value in both places.

```
UPDATE stats
SET counter = counter - ?
WHERE id = ?
  AND counter > ?;
```

Which you'd call with some pseudocode like `sql.execute(decrement, id, decrement)`

If the counter is *never* supposed to go below 1, I would add a constraint on that field.  `counter INTEGER CHECK (counter > 0)`

Answer (score 4):

Another way...

```
UPDATE stats SET counter = (
  CASE WHEN counter > 1 
  THEN (counter - 1) 
  ELSE 1 END
) WHERE id = 24235;
```

Comment: For changing a single row, this is fine.  If you're changing a lot of rows, where a significant percentage may have counters already at 1, I would be interested to know if Postgres is smart enough to take advantage of an index on counter.